Failed to enable groovy TypeChecked and type-checking-extension in the config file
I need to enable the TypeChecked when compile my project. And I also want to customize the compile error output for certain types of compilation error, so I write a Type-Checking-Extension according to the doc. I build my project with maven and GMavenPlus-plugin. Both TypeCheck and type-checking-extension do not work. The compilation successed.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.example:springboot_groovy >--------------------
[INFO] Building springboot_groovy 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ springboot_groovy ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ springboot_groovy ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jianh\Desktop\bendi_ht\springboot_groovy\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gplus:3.0.2:compile (default) @ springboot_groovy ---
[INFO] Using isolated classloader, without GMavenPlus classpath.
[INFO] Using Groovy 3.0.8 to perform compile.
[INFO] Parallel parsing disabled.
[INFO] Compiled 6 files.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.922 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-07-24T15:19:20+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here's a demo of my project:
DemoController.groovy:
// a demo groovy source code with error!

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String sayHello() {

        // use an undeclared variable
        println robot
    }
}

config.groovy
// I hope to enable TypeChecked and customized extension

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(
        TypeChecked,
        extensions: ['CheckExtension.groovy'])
)

CheckExtension.groovy
// when meet an undeclared var which name is 'robot', then add customized error info

unresolvedVariable { var ->
    if ('robot'==var.name) {
        //customized compile error info
        addStaticTypeError("Customize Error Info: hahaha", var)
    }
}

The structure of my project is a little strange, however, I'm not allowed to change it:
project_basedir/
--groovy/
----DemoController.groovy
--groovyCompileCheck/
----config.groovy
----CheckExtension.groovy
--src/
----main/
------java/

I use GMavenPlus plugin in the maven:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sources>

            <!-- add project groovy source -->
            <source>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/groovy</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </source>

            <!-- add type-check-extension to classpath -->
            <source>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/groovyCompileCheck</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </source>
        </sources>

        <!-- set the config.groovy for compilation -->
        <configScript>${project.basedir}/groovyCompileCheck/config.groovy</configScript>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I wonder what's wrong with my config? Thanks!
Moreover, my real need is to customize the compile error output for calling a method with miss-matching numbers of parameters, e.g., a method definition with 2 params, but only give 1 when call this method.
In this condition, what should the customized extension be like? I've tried to read the doc, but that's really difficult for me...

Are you trying to have this extension used within the same project?  That's not going to work since this project would need to be compiled first before it could load the extension to compile the rest of the code.  I think you're going to have to have the extension as a separate project that produces a jar, then use that jar in whatever you want to customize the compiler with.
The one drawback to extension methods is that they must be on the classpath of the compiler prior to compiling your source.  So separating out the compiler extension into it's own project, then using dependencies in maven to pull in your jar file of this extension in a 2nd project is required.
